# Recommendations for a free web analytics tool which works behind a company intranet?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, analytics

I'm developing a site for an internal Corporate and Social Responsibility page. Lately I'm trying to implement some form of analytics - simple click counter will do, but obviously the more data the better.

Through research I found there's alot of tools on the internet such as Google Analytics and Piwik but we can't use them because the intranet is not a full formed domain name for the former (we also probably need it to be local!) and the server we're hosting our site on does not have MySQL for the latter.

The site is very basic - HTML and CSS mixed with JS. Nothing fancy.

Is there a simple plug and play tool I could use to help this?

Comment: Where do you want to store the logs? What technology do you want to use server-side?

Comment: You don't have MySQL available... there is free MySQL; would you be willing/able to install that? Do you have some alternate database available?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt we're piggy-backing on a development server at the moment, so probably nothing that requires installation

Comment: @NickWilde we cannot unfortunately, as we're piggybacking someone else's dev environment so we shouldn't install anything substantial. The server is running nginx and has sybase installed

Comment: nginx already logs quite a bit of data: http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/8/27/reading-nginx-web-logs

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine ah that makes sense - if somewhat sucks for what options you have. Does the server work with Python? PHP? Ruby (ie Ruby-On-Rails/ROR)? any other server side languages?

Comment: @NickWilde it has Python installed, don't think so about the others...

Answer (score 2):

@evilwashingmachine

Hi - why dont you just trawl your webserver's logs?

For example, on Windows, Logparser (and the gui Logparser Studio - http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-log-parser-studio.aspx) can do a count distinct(c-ip) from a web site log that will give you how many times each unique IP appears in the log - you can filter it down using where clauses to only certain pages, page elements, user agents etc.

You have the raw data there and the full customisability of a script to report on whatever you want. There are plenty of script examples available online too.

Isn't that pretty much what Google Analytics does?